# I have a navbar. How do I set the height of the items to be 100% of the navbar?

Tags: html, css, height, navbar

I've been trying to make a navbar but I haven't quite been succesful. The navbar div has a height of 60px, however, I can't seem to be able to increase the height of the inside elements in any way. (except padding) What am I doing wrong?
[What I'm getting](https://prnt.sc/qkj8lh)
[What I'm trying to get](https://prnt.sc/qkj8pi)

```css
#navbar {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 60px;
      background: #deff00;
      box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
      top: 85px;
    }
    #navbar ul {
      height: 100%;
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .navbar-link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      height: 60px;
      padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .navbar-link:hover {
      background: #adc703;
    }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" style="font-weight: bold;" class="navbar-link"
                >ÚVODNÍ STRÁNKA</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-link">ŠKOLA</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">STUDIUM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">FOTOGALERIE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">KONTAKT</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#navbar {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 60px;
      background: #deff00;
      box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
      top: 85px;
}
#navbar ul {
      height: 100%;
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
}

#navbar li {
      display: table;
} 

.navbar-link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      height: 60px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: table-cell;
}

.navbar-link:hover {
      background: #adc703;
}
```

Just added `display: table;` for the li, and `vertical-align: middle;display: table-cell` for the a tag, sometimes this old technics fit perfect)
Codepen: https://codepen.io/Liveindream/pen/mdyXmxj?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this question correctly, you want to raise the  elements in height. The thing that is constricting you from doing that is inside of your CSS

```
#navbar ul {
height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Remove `align-items: center;` from  `#navbar ul`

So that it looks like this:

```
#navbar ul {
height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Now you should be able to increase and/or decrease it in height to correctly align it onto your div tag the way you'd like.

Comment: That wasn't quite it. I probably phrased it weirdly, I added screenshots of what I'm getting and trying to get to the original post.